# Changing input method in term mode

Tags: input-method

If I try to change input method in emacs and send to some text.

`buffer is read only` message is shown in minibuffer.

How can I use other input method in emacs term mode?

I'm using emacs multi-term.

Answer (score 1):

Are you unable to toggle off the read-only-mode? Have you tried using the `read-only-mode` command? You can toggle the input method on/off using `C-\`, to type commands using latin letters.

I managed to get it working, check out if it is running on `char-mode` or `line-mode`, then run the term-line-mode, if it's not getting input right nor toggling the input method with `C-\`.

Comment: Is "C-\" working in term char mode? It dosen't work. it's only working in term line mode.

Comment: No, you're right, it doesn't toggle the input method in the terminal, fcitx works fine though. I'll edit the answer to correct that.